# { message: 'Unsupported post request. ,, type: 'GraphMethodException', code: 100, fbtrace_id: 'HHiDmF0kcZP' }

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

This is my server.js file. I want to post a message on my facebook wall but when I am running this server.js I am getting the following error.

```
var config=require('./config');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var morgan=require('morgan');
var nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
var FB=require('fb');
var app = express();

FB.appid="yyyyyy";
FB.permissions=['publish_actions','status_update'];
FB.forceDialogAuth=true;
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


mongoose.connect(config.database,function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('database connected');
});



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/public/app/views/index.html' );
});

aPP.post('/post',function(req,res){
FB.setAccessToken('xxxxxxxx');
var body='hello people';
FB.api(yyyyyy/feed','post',{message:body},function(res){
    if(!res ||res.error){
        console.log(!res ? 'error' : res.error);
        return;
    }
    console.log('post id:' + res.id);
});
```

});

```
app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('server running at  '+config.port);

});


var api=require('./routes/api')(app,express,nodemailer);
app.use('/api',api);
```

And the error I am getting is:

{ message: 'Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api',
  type: 'GraphMethodException',
  code: 100,
  fbtrace_id: 'HHiDmF0kcZP' }

I am getting this error just after the post reques.. I have generated the tokenaccess earlier which I was using now. I'm new to this. I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

It is `publish_actions`, not `publish-actions`. Btw, you can always debug your Token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Make sure you get asked for the correct permissions in the authorization process and make sure the Token is valid and includes the `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: Yes the token is valid. I have included publish_actions permission in my server.js only. In place of me/feed when I am placing "myid"/feed, I am getting the following error: { message: 'Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api',
  type: 'GraphMethodException',
  code: 100,
  fbtrace_id: 'HHiDmF0kcZP' }. Otherwise the same as above. Please help.

Comment: /me/feed is correct. that error means that publish_actions is not authorized. please read my answer again and make sure the token includes publish_actions. it surely does not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `yyyyyy`

`FB.appid="yyyyyy";` and

`FB.api(yyyyyy/feed','post',{message:body},function(res){`

is the same, the answer you are looking for is that you cannot post to an app feed.

HTTP POST /app/feed results in

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```